Autorest (swagger) question, how to transform/use directive to get rid of duplicate names
I’m looking into autorest but encounter an issue with duplicate names, one of the parts in the yaml file that I try to transform into a powershell module is as follows:
      parameters:
        - description: token
          in: path
          name: token
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - description: <a href="(url edited)"  target="_blank">Generate your application key</a>
          in: query
          name: key
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - description: <a href="(url edited)"  target="_blank">Getting a token from a user</a>
          in: query
          name: token
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string

As you can see, there’s a path with the name ‘token’ and a query (string) with the name ‘token’, both would be needed for the API. The generating of the code goes well, but at building the module, is gives the error:

error CS0100: The parameter name 'token' is a duplicate.

Which is logical, as in the public async function it shows these variables (string token, string token, string key).
I’m assuming I need to do some kind of transformation while using autorest with the inputfle, but online in the documentation I can’t seem to find many examples on how to do that.
